How do I stream data from my Neurosky Mindwave Mobile 2 to my Raspberry Pi 4?
I have managed to connect and pair my Neurosky Mindwave Mobile 2 to my Raspberry Pi 4. But when I try and stream data from the headset to my Raspberry Pi, my code says "No data received".
Here's my code:
import serial

# Define the port and settings for Mindwave
port = '/dev/rfcomm0'
baud_rate = 57600  # Mindwave typically uses 57600 bps
timeout_duration = 2  # Timeout in seconds

try:
    # Open the serial connection
    with serial.Serial(port, baud_rate, timeout=timeout_duration) as headset:
        print("Connected to Mindwave on Raspberry Pi via /dev/rfcomm0")
        
        # Continuously read data
        while True:
            data = headset.read(1)  # Read one byte at a time
            if data:
                print("Data received:", data.hex())  # Print the data in hexadecimal format
            else:
                print("No data received. Waiting...")

except serial.SerialException as e:
    print("Error connecting to headset:", e)
except Exception as e:
    print("An unexpected error occurred:", e)


What am I missing?
I tried using headset.write(b'\xC0') to see if the headset needed to be told to start streaming data but my python program stopped printing after "Connected to Mindwave Mobile". I expected data but got nothing. It wouldn't even print "No data received. Waiting..."
